# What is best practice to serialize foreign key fields in a REST-ful api

Tags: json, django, rest, serialization, django-rest-framework

I want to write a Django app with a REST-ful api. Django REST framework offers three built-in model serializers: ModelSerializer which serializes to something like this

```
{
    'normal_field': 'value',
    'foreign_key_field': 42
}
```

and HyperlinkedModelSerializer which serializes to something like this

```
{
    'normal_field': 'value',
    'foreign_key_field': 'http://domain/api/myothermodel/11'
}
```

My question is whether there is another good way to serialize the data so that the client directly knows which fields have to be resolved and which fields not.

Example: A client which receives this

```
{ 
    'foo': 'http://domain/api/myothermodel/11',
    'bar': 'http://otherdomain/api/myothermodel/12'
}
```

does not know whether foo or bar should be a resolveable foreign key field and not a plain url. Something like:

```
{ 
    'foo': 'http://domain/api/myothermodel/11', # Here the client might know that this is only a plain url.
    'bar': {
            '_foreignkey': true,  # Tells the client that this field should behave as a foreign key which has to be resolved first
            'url': 'http://otherdomain/api/myothermodel/12'
        }
}
```

Is there any standard or best practice? Or is best practice that the client does not know this from the JSON but from other code it has or gets from the server?

**Update:** Optional you can add which way is best practice for some wellknown client side libs like AngularJS.

Comment: That's actually an interesting question I haven't thought myself. For us the frontend guys know in advance what have to be resolvable

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by **a foreign key which has to be resolved first**? By resolved, do you mean the related instance has a resource location end point in your REST API? And by resolved first, first before what specific operation?

Comment: Yes: "Resolve" means that data represents information to get the related instance. "First" means that I finally want to show the instance and all related instances on my site. So the client hast to follow all relations and fetch the instances before the page can be rendered. BUT: In my first example it is not self evident that the data is such "resolvable" information but not just some plain data. Does this make it more clear?

Comment: I see, you are aiming for a self-describing API, more or less something akin to HATEOAS. AFAIK, there's no standard for this yet with JSON, though there is some [work on that front](http://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/). Whatever design you choose, documenting the API is a good idea.

Comment: @Fiver: Thanks. If you setup your post as answer, I can accept it and (later) award the bounty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears you are after a self-describing and explorable web API service, which is actually a core feature of the original REST concept referred to as [**Hypermedia as the Engine of Application State (HATEOAS)**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS). Essentially, a HATEOAS-compliant web service does not rely upon any prior knowledge of the system's resources other than the initial URL entry point.

This is in contrast to a [**Service Oriented Architecture (SOA)**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture) where individual services are basically unassociated and require prior knowledge of their existence to string together several service calls to accomplish some task with multiple, possibly related resources.

Most references to a REST API are actually not fully RESTful, and should more accurately be described as web APIs, as they are more in-line with the SOA design: a set of URLs to both specific instances and collections of instances of a particular type. This would also include the use of different HTTP verbs (GET, PATCH, POST, PUT) for various actions to perform on those resources. The Django REST Framework (DRF) actually has a page on this topic with links to some great resources on the true RESTful design, including the dissertation by Roy Fielding:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/rest-hypermedia-hateoas

I would speculate that the current use of the term "REST API" relates to the revelation of many developers that implementing a truly RESTful service is far from trivial and in many cases would be over-engineered for the particular use case. Perhaps this is a good example of "perfection as the enemy of the good." For the case of using AngularJS as a client-side framework for interacting with a Django backend via DRF, this is especially true. There is nothing in the AngularJS framework that parses a truly RESTful design to automagically provide the various application states possible for a given resource. Plus, the same developer(s) will usually be responsible for both the JavaScript and Python code, so the lack of a self-describing API is not a major barrier to development.

Regarding the implementation of a truly RESTful API in JSON, there are a couple projects attempting to facilitate this, namely the [**Hypertext Application Language (HAL)**](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) and [**JSON Linked Data (JSON-LD)**](http://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/). However, I am not aware that DRF natively supports either of these, so you would likely have to architect your serializers to conform to one of them, or roll your own Django REST implementation.

Finally, whatever design you choose, fully documenting the API is usually a good idea. This is true regardless of whether the API is web-based or in some native programming language. Part of the allure for the separation of concerns that a web API provides is that 3rd parties can consume resources to build applications or pipelines that you haven't considered, not to mention the advantages in maintainability for future changes to the code base for your project. There are a couple interesting projects [mentioned on the DRF site](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/documenting-your-api) to assist in documenting an API. [Swagger](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger) is a particularly awesome one, developed by the same developer that provided the older Django REST Framework Docs package.

Comment: Great. I will discuss this with my coworkers and we will see what to use. Thank you very much.